# Merge duplicates on condition

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table in a PostgreSQL db

```
id | value_1 | value_2
-----------------------------
1  | 100     | 10
1  | NULL    | 20
2  | 100     | 20
3  | 100     | 12
4  | 100     | 16
5  | NULL    | 200
5  | 400     | 200
5  | 580     | 200
```

I would like to retain the record with the max value given in `value_1` and remove all other duplicated records (have the same `id`) so that the query will reduce the table to:

```
id | value_1 | value_2
-----------------------------
1  | 100     | 10
2  | 100     | 20
3  | 100     | 12
4  | 100     | 16
5  | 580     | 200
```

Comment: By "remove" you mean "not select" them from a table, or "delete them" (permanently)? Start, as *always*, by declaring your version of Postgres, and a proper table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). Add cardinalities!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done using PostgreSQL's (proprietary) `distinct on ()` operator:

```
select distinct on (id) *
from the_table
order by id, value_1 desc nulls last;
```

Comment: You need to add [`NULLS LAST`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=79292626d97da44c258251d6d07945b7) to that! Nice, using DISTINCT ON as a proxy for ROW_NUMBER() - more performant!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW: yes, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- You want to actually `DELETE` duplicates from the table.
- `id` is defined `NOT NULL`.
- There is at least one not-null `value_1` per distinct `id`.
- Only few duplicated to be deleted.

```
DELETE FROM tbl t0
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t1
   WHERE  t1.id = t0.id
   AND   (t1.value_1 > t0.value_1  -- a row with bigger value exists
       OR t0.value_1 IS NULL)      -- or NULL 
   );
```

An index on `(id)` or even `(id, value_1)` would be helpful in this case. Related:

- [Delete duplicate rows from small table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63759611/939860)
- [How to delete duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746213/939860)

After cleaning up, a `UNIQUE` index on `(id)` would keep it that way. (Plus making it `NOT NULL`.)

If any of my assumptions do not hold (be more specific!), a different solution may be in order.